# java.net.ConnectException: the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: java, windows, sockets

I am trying to check the connectivity by pinging various IPs by the following code.

```
ipAdd = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
            boolean isConnected = ipAdd.isReachable(3000);
```

But I get this error.

```
java.net.ConnectException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
```

The reson being there are around 1000 threads doing this process simultaneously. I have thought about keeping these IPs in a queue. But for that I want to know the maximum number of Threads I can use. Is there any way to find out the buffer space so that I can figure out the number of threads to be triggered simultaneously that will run the above code. 
I would appreciate any other work around/solution apart from the queueing method.

Comment: Have you [googled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx) today?

Comment: I have gone through that link already. I understand that its the OS' limitation but  I made a sepearate program in which I am hitting 3000 IPs at a time easily. But in my application code, its showing this error for 1000 threads itself.

Comment: Does any connection get open on calling isReachable method. If yes then is it required to close it? Also let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this exception occurs because you have exceeded the limit of ports that can be used by your application.
do you close your connections?

Comment: I am closing all my sockets. But sockets are created only if that IP is reachable. The exception occurs at the isReachable method call. There are around 1000 isReachable calls made at a time(1000 Threads)

Comment: Well, even if the Socket is created later, physically, java HAS to reserve one port to check, if the address is reachable. If whyever these ports do not get freed, than that could overflow your pool.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? What should be my step after this                                                          boolean isConnected = ipAdd.isReachable(3000);